# R console doesn't respond to code changes

Tags: r, console, dataframe, write.table

R console sometimes acts very strangely when I paste code and execute in it. After executing code that creates an output file, the console from then on will only generate that specific output, regardless if I make changes to the code.

The problem can be explained using the below code as an example. `dataframeA` and `dataframeB` are the contents of two csv format spreadsheets read in with read.csv

```
>CombinedCols <- data.frame(dataframeA, dataframeB) 
>write.table(CombinedCols, file = "/Users/Username/Results.csv",
              append = TRUE, sep = ",")
```

When I change the contents of `dataframeA` or `dataframeB` and re-execute the code in console the file Results.csv would be generated exactly as if I had made no changes to dataframeA or B.

I have no idea what this situation is even called.
Does anyone have any insight about what the issue is here?

Comment: You need to add the specific code you are using to "change the content of dataframeA and dataframeB".

Comment: I notice you are using `append = TRUE` so each time you call `write.table`, it will write more stuff at the bottom of your file. Maybe you are only scanning the top of your file hence not noticing any change... And maybe you should remove that option if that's not what you want.

Comment: >append = TRUE  is just so I can more easily track the effects (or lack thereof) of changing the code. Having the parameter as FALSE does not affect this problem I've been having.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By combining dataframe A and B, a new object CombinedCols is created. After that, there is no link between CombinedCols and its original objects, dataframe A and B. Therefore, any changes in dataframe A is not reflected in CombinedCols.

In order for the changes in data frame A to be reflected in CombinedCols, you need re-create it with the new, edited, data frames.

Comment: As I read it, OP was referring to rerunning the full code (including the generation of `CombinedCols`).

Comment: Hmm, then we need more details from the OP, including a reproducible example.